# Vue data does not display value on console but does display on component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to retrieve a global session value and set it to the vue variable. The problem is, the id variable is not displaying any value on the console but does display the value on the vue component. I've checked with the vue devtools and the id does contain the correct value.

**Vue Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{id}}</h1> // the id does displays the value
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
          id:'',
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('api/studentlecture').then(response => this.id = response.data).catch(function(error){console.log(error)
        });     
        console.log(this.id) 
    },
    methods:{

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $id= session('userID');
    return json_encode($id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the axios call is asynchronous. The JavaScript engine will execute the axios request, and while it is waiting it will continue executing the code.

You are trying to log `this.id` while it has not yet been assigned. If you want to log the value, you have to put it in the callback of your axios function.

```
axios.get('api/studentlecture')
    .then(response => {
        this.id = response.data;
        console.log(this.id); // <== Here
    })
    .catch(function(error){console.log(error)});
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `console.log(this.id)` is executed before `axios.get()` could resolve it's promise.

There are a few solution for this.

First one is to move `console.log()` inside `then()`.

```
created() { 
  axios.get('api/studentlecture').then(response => {
    this.id = response.data;
    console.log(this.id);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

Or you can make use of `async/await` to wait the promise to resolve

```
async created() { 
  try {
    // This will wait until promise resolve
    const response = await axios.get('api/studentlecture');
    this.id = response.data;
    console.log(this.id);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

You can learn more about promise [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)

And more about async/await difference with promise [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/async-await-vs-promises-4fe98d11038f)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code below:

```js
/*FRONT-END VUE*/

this.axios.get("https://localhost:8000/api/v1/data").then((response)=>{
                    this.data=response.data;
                    console.log(this.data);
                    if(this.data.success){
                      

                    }
 });
```

```html
/*BACK-END LARAVEL*/
 
 function getData(){
    $result = array('success'=>true,'data'=>$data);
    
    return Response()->json($result);
 }
```